# BIRT IRunAndRenderTask consumes a lot of resources

Tags: java, memory, cpu-usage, birt

I'm using BIRT to create reports in my application using the following code:

```
task = birtService.createBIRTTask(outputDesign);
setScriptedDataSetParameters(builder, task);
task.setParameterValues(parameterValues);
PDFRenderOption pdfOptions = new PDFRenderOption();
pdfOptions.setOutputFileName(file.getAbsolutePath());
pdfOptions.setOutputFormat(PDFRenderOption.OUTPUT_FORMAT_PDF);
task.setRenderOption(pdfOptions);
task.run();
```

My problem is that when i'm generating reports with large amounts of data(~2.5 million rows) the process running the BIRT task is consuming approximately 60% of the computer's resources(the machine is well equipped - 24 cores).

My question is if there is any way to configure the task to use a limited amount of resources(up to 1GB/percentage of the available resources etc.) even in the expense of the report generation taking more time.

Thanks :)

Comment: Isn't this something that the OS should be responsible for?

Comment: i don't think so... just like the OS is not limiting the max heap size of a java application - you define in the Xmx parameter when you run it.